# Unable to install Apache Cordova for VS 2013 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, apache-cordova

I use VS 2013 Community currently. I installed Apache Cordova. Installation completed successfully. Then I started VS 2013 and tried to create a new Apache Cordova project. I saw that there is no BLANK PROJECT link under the Javascript menu, but "Install tolls for Apache Cordova"

I uninstalled both VS 2013 and Apache Cordova. Then installed again but nothing changed. You'll find screenshot attached below. It shows the menu after installing Apache Cordova.

Now, I can not create any apache Cordova project.

What can I do for that?

Thanks in advance for your support.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHKbs.png)

Comment: Visual Studio Community with Update 5 and Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2013 - CTP 3.2 are currently installed.

Answer (score 0):

Tools for Apache Cordova (TACO) for VS 2013 is only served as "Technical Preview".Great changes and improvements has been made for TACO in VS2015. 
Currently VS2015 is the only version that officially support TACO.

We strongly recommend that developers migrate to VS2015 when using TACO.